# Possible to find all client side collections from the console?

Tags: meteor, minimongo

I have a meteor.js application and I would like to take a look at what information is included in all client side collections.  There are about 20 client side collections and I know that I can access them one by one and have them return their documents like so:

```
Meteor.myCollection.find().fetch()
```

But I'm wondering if there is a way to get all meteor.js collections that are on the client side and loop through them.  Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the collection instances:

```
var collections = _.chain(_.keys(window))
  .filter(function(k) {return window[k] instanceof Meteor.Collection;})
  .map(function(k) {return window[k];})
  .value();
```

To get the collection names:

```
var names = _.filter(_.keys(window), function(key) {
  return window[key] instanceof Meteor.Collection;
});
```

Comment: If you want to know which collections have also been populated, you can do `var populated = _.chain(collections).filter(function(cc) { return cc.find().count() > 0; }).map(function(cx) { return { name: cx._name, count: cx.find().count() }; }).value();`

Answer (score 0):

you need this package :-

```
https://github.com/dburles/mongo-collection-instances
```

then you can do

```
Mongo.Collections.getAll()
```

It gets used in the really useful "Mongol", which allows you to examine your collections / subscriptions on the client side.  This tool sounds more like what you are really wanting to achieve

https://github.com/msavin/Mongol